# Can “to” ever be a Prep or a Particle before “be”

Tags: syntax, parts-of-speech, infinitive

Can “to” ever be a Prep or a Particle before “be”?  If so can anyone think of an example?

Comment: Historically, what is now called the "infinitive marker" **was** a preposition: in OE, the infinitive acted as a nominal and was declined like a noun. And there are to this day expressions in which it is difficult to argue that the prepositional character has been completely obliterated by grammaticalization: for instance, *Prof. Sartorius went on to be named Chairman of the Department*.

Answer (score 5):

"Can where he went to be revealed?"
from:

Q (where he went to can be revealed)
Q (someone can reveal Q (he went to where))

Schematically, we start with

```
... can reveal ... [PP to where]
```

which is converted to the passive,

```
... [PP to where] ... can be revealed
```

the "where" moves out of the way between "to" and "be" because the question word has to be at the beginning of the embedded question,

```
... [PP to] can be revealed
```

and finally "can" moves out of the way because it has to be inverted with the subject of the upstairs Q,

```
... [PP to] be ...
```